# Ruby-on-rails - Destroy - Error: No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `destroy`

In my view, I have:

```
#delete_archive_modal.modal.fade
.modal-header
  %h3
    %i.icon-exclamation-sign
    Attention
.modal-body
  %p= "Are you sure you want to delete this portal?"
.modal-footer
  %a.btn{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :href => "#"} Cancel
  = link_to 'Delete', delete_portal_path(portal)
```

Routes:

```
resources :portals do
resources :pill_tabs, only: [:show, :edit]

resources :page_urls do
  collection do
    get :redirects
  end
end

resources :zero_touch_configs do
  member do
    get :history
  end
end

member do
  get :navigation
  get :history
  get :sitemap
  get :url_list
  post :generate_sitemap
  post :add_modules
  post :archive
  post :delete
end

collection do
  get :index, path: '/'
  get :new, path: '/new(/:portal_type)'
  get :accessible_sites
  get :archive_index
  get :delete
end
```

And in my controller:

```
  def destroy
   @portal = Portal.find(params[:id])
   @portal.destroy
   flash[:notice] = 'Portal deleted successfully.'
   redirect_to action: :archive_index
 end
```

routes:

```
                                              portals GET       /portals(.:format)                                                                                                    portals#index
                                                      GET       /portals/new(/:portal_type)(.:format)                                                                                 portals#new
                             accessible_sites_portals GET       /portals/accessible_sites(.:format)                                                                                   portals#accessible_sites
                                archive_index_portals GET       /portals/archive_index(.:format)                                                                                      portals#archive_index
                                       delete_portals GET       /portals/delete(.:format)                                                                                             portals#delete
                         history_portal_stack_wrapper GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id/history(.:format)                                                              stack_wrappers#history
                          drafts_portal_stack_wrapper GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id/drafts(.:format)                                                               stack_wrappers#drafts
                           purge_portal_stack_wrapper GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id/purge(.:format)                                                                stack_wrappers#purge
                     all_drafts_portal_stack_wrappers GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/drafts(.:format)                                                                   stack_wrappers#all_drafts
                                portal_stack_wrappers GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers(.:format)                                                                          stack_wrappers#index
                                                      POST      /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers(.:format)                                                                          stack_wrappers#create
                             new_portal_stack_wrapper GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/new(.:format)                                                                      stack_wrappers#new
                            edit_portal_stack_wrapper GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 stack_wrappers#edit
                                 portal_stack_wrapper GET       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id(.:format)                                                                      stack_wrappers#show
                                                      PATCH     /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id(.:format)                                                                      stack_wrappers#update
                                                      PUT       /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id(.:format)                                                                      stack_wrappers#update
                                                      DELETE    /portals/:portal_id/stack_wrappers/:id(.:format)                                                                      stack_wrappers#destroy
                         history_portal_config_bundle GET       /portals/:portal_id/config_bundles/:id/history(.:format)                                                              config_bundles#history
                                portal_config_bundles GET       /portals/:portal_id/config_bundles(.:format)                                                                          config_bundles#index
                                                      POST      /portals/:portal_id/config_bundles(.:format)                                                                          config_bundles#create
                             new_portal_config_bundle GET       /portals/:portal_id/config_bundles/new(.:format)                                                                      config_bundles#new
                            edit_portal_config_bundle GET       /portals/:portal_id/config_bundles/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 config_bundles#edit
                                 portal_config_bundle GET       /portals/:portal_id/config_bundles/:id(.:format)
```

But I am getting a routing error and don't know where to go from here...

`No route matches [GET] "/portals/asdg/delete"`

Can anyone share a guide or point me to documentation that helps me understand what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you please show delete_portal_path from `rake routes` here?

Comment: @ashvin Routes added. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
= link_to 'Delete', portal_path(portal), method: :delete
```

Here are the all 7 routes for `portal`

```
              portals GET    /portals(.:format)                                 portals#index
                      POST   /portals(.:format)                                 portals#create
           new_portal GET    /portals/new(.:format)                             portals#new
          edit_portal GET    /portals/:id/edit(.:format)                        portals#edit
               portal GET    /portals/:id(.:format)                             portals#show
                      PATCH  /portals/:id(.:format)                             portals#update
                      PUT    /portals/:id(.:format)                             portals#update
                      DELETE /portals/:id(.:format)                             portals#destroy
```

And in your routes you have `delete_portal` path will exist because of

```
member do
  post :delete
end
```

If you want to call this then you have do define method for this action in your controller and call this path with `method: :post`

But in RESTful routes delete action have always `DELETE` method, see in above routes.

Comment: Thank you @ashvin! How can I define the method in the controller? 'def delete'?

Comment: Yes define new method in controller `def delete # do some stuff here end` for `delete_portal_path`

Comment: But `destroy` action is already define in your controller use that method using `portal_path(portal), method: :delete` to delete object, instead of custom route for `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in your `link_to` tag.

1. You used `delete_portal_path(portal)` but if you run `rake routes` on your console you will see no such route exist. it have `portal_path(portal)`.
2. You need to specify method type in route in case of Show(GET default), update(PUT) and delete(DELETE). Because all share same path `portal_path(portal)`.

So your final route should be:

```
= link_to 'Delete', portal_path(portal), method: :delete
```

More detail [`here`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define http method when you use delete

```
 = link_to 'Delete', portal_path(portal), method: :delete
```

It will work.